# Why is the SPA application not creating a database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-spa

I have followed a microsoft video trying to make the single page application and it doesnt create or connect to my sql instance even though I have other applications using code first. For example the connection string was...

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication2-201265113324;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But I get an error saying

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Its really strange because my other application with the connectionstring...

```
<add name="PteDotNetContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=Localhost;Database=PteDotNet;Trusted_Connection=true;" />
```

Works fine and will connect no problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not provide a connection string or connection string name to the `DbContext` constructor, it will try to find a connection name that matches the (inherited) `DbContext` class name.

Hence you can either change the name of the connection string

```
<add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication2-201265113324;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Or provide the name of the connection string in the constructor

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     public MyDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection") {}
}
```